# _.isUndefined() is not working in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    if (!_.isUndefined(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID) && !_.isUndefined(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET)) {
        paypal.configure({
            mode: 'live',
            client_id: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET,
        });
    }
} else {
    paypal.configure({
        mode: 'sandbox',
        client_id: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET,
    });
}
```

This is the code I'm using. I'm explicitly checking for `undefined` and then trying to configure the PayPal Rest SDK.

But, I'm getting this error in TypeScript:

> Argument of type '{ mode: string; client_id: string | undefined;
>   client_secret: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'ConfigureOptions'.   Types of property 'client_id' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Why does TypeScript still think that the variable could be `undefined`..? Is this specific to environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing that lodash's `isUndefined()` doesn't function as a type guard for you.  It looks like this is a known limitation in TypeScript (related to [Microsoft/TypeScript#11483](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483) and [Microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530)).  In short, doing narrowing on string-indexed properties (all properties are string-indexed in `process.env`) is too expensive for the compiler.  So it doesn't do it.  The suggested workaround is to copy the properties you care about to their own variables, like so:

```
const paypalClientId = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID
const paypalClientSecret = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET
if (!_.isUndefined(paypalClientId) && !_.isUndefined(paypalClientSecret)) {
  paypal.configure({
    mode: 'live',
    client_id: paypalClientId, // ok, narrowed to string
    client_secret: paypalClientSecret, // ok, narrowed to string
  });
}
```

That should allow the compiler to verify that the values are defined.  If you don't care about the compiler doing the verification for you and you're happy asserting the defined values yourself, you can use the exclamation mark as @FilipeSabella suggests.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Okay. Let me test that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already checking if the keys are undefined, you can append a `!` to the key to force the type.

```
client_id: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID!,
client_secret: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET!,
```